# How to set the permission of the file based one the suffix during creating using vim?

Tags: vim

When I create a new python script, I usually want to make it executable. I can do it in two steps: first create the file using `vim`; the set the permission using `chmod`. The question is: is it possible to merge the two steps into one?

What I would like to see is: when I create the file from vim, it will check the suffix and set proper permissions (configurable). And I expect it also works for files like .sh, .exe... Thanks.

Comment: There is a script in http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3366, which might be useful, but I haven't managed to make it work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following; it checks the file's *shebang* (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python`) instead of the file extension.

```
" On the initial save, make the file executable if it has a shebang line,
" e.g. #!/usr/bin/env ...
" This uses the user's umask for determining the executable bits to be set.
function! s:GetShebang()
    return matchstr(getline(1), '^#!\S\+')
endfunction
function! s:MakeExecutable()
    if exists('b:executable') | return | endif
    let l:shebang = s:GetShebang()
    if empty(l:shebang) ||
    \   executable(expand('%:p')) ||
    \   ! executable('chmod')
        return
    endif

    call system('chmod +x ' . shellescape(expand('%')))
    if v:shell_error
        echohl ErrorMsg
        echomsg 'Cannot make file executable: ' . v:shell_error
        echohl None
        let b:executable = 0
    else
        echomsg 'Detected shebang' l:shebang . '; made file executable as' getfperm(expand('%'))
        let b:executable = 1
    endif
endfunction
augroup ExecutableFileDetect
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost * call <SID>MakeExecutable()
augroup END
```

Comment: you can use getfperm and setfperm for platform compatibility.

Comment: Seems this should work for me... How can I make it work? Inserting this snippet to my .vimrc? Thanks.

Comment: Simply adding it to .vimrc works. Thanks. But another minor question: seems that it's executed every time of saving the file, not just "On the initial save". Is this known? Through it's not a problem at the moment for me, but I'm thinking that sometimes we do want to make it non-executable.

Comment: @ingo-karkat Why not `echoerr`?

Comment: Yes, this is executed every time, but on subsequent ones the file is already executable, so nothing happens. You can introduce a buffer-local flag to limit to first save; by setting that, you could also avoid making a file executable.

Comment: @phd: echoerr from within a function causes ugly multi-line output with a stack trace.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on the `buffer-local flag`. Do you have an example?

Comment: @dlz: See my edit. If you want to avoid making a file executable, just `:let b:executable = 0` before `:write`ing the buffer.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Thanks for the update. But if I understand correctly, this flag is only in the buffer, means that when it will be forgotten in the next write-out? For example, if I make it non-executable first and then modify it, it will be saved as executable again by default?

Comment: @dlz: Buffers persist throughout a Vim session, i.e. until you close Vim.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, maybe it's another question: is there a way to check if this this a new file or just updating an existing file? I would like to only do this for new files....

Comment: @dlz: Yes, you could set a flag `b:newfile` on `BufNewFile`, and then check the existence of that. Unfortunately, it's much more complex than that to handle all cases.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, thanks a lot for the quick and patient reply. Your suggestion works. I now have exactly what I want. Have a nice day!